# create android layout using json response

Tags: android, jsonp

I need to create an game info list using this json response in android:

```
 {"count":"2","useruid":"100003264774181","games":[{"lastupdate":"2012-01-17 13:55:39","gametype":"R","players":{"2":"100002913406085,Prabir Kumar D,6sq6","1":"100003264774181,Avinash S,twyq"},"turnuid":"100002913406085","score":{"2":"0","1":"18"},"playerscount":2,"dic":"twl","active":"y","canforcewin":"n","showmsg":"n","lastmove":"HIDE,r,18","gameid":"85030616","tilesinbag":"68"},{"lastupdate":"2012-01-17 13:50:55","gametype":"R","players":{"2":"100000145226351,Sayak K,0r9o","1":"100003264774181,Avinash S,kltv"},"turnuid":"100000145226351","score":{"2":"0","1":"26"},"playerscount":2,"dic":"twl","active":"y","canforcewin":"n","showmsg":"n","lastmove":"BOX,r,26","gameid":"85030764","tilesinbag":"68"}]}
```

my xml is linearlayout>>frame layout>> scrollview>> linear layout-- android:orientation="horizontal">> text view

currently i m using this but got stuck..

```
JSONObject jresponse=response.getJsonResponseFor(myRequest);

                String result=jresponse.toString();
                System.out.println(" jresponse is here  "+jresponse.toString());


                JSONArray jArray = jresponse.getJSONArray("games");
                int max=jArray.length();
                System.out.println("array length::"+max);

                for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
                   {

                JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
                JSONArray names = obj.names();

                for (int k = 0; k < names.length(); k++) 
                    {
                        String name = names.getString(k);
                      String value= obj.getString(name);
                           createtableLayout();  
                    }

                   }
```

the  `createtableLayout()` should add the data dynamically to the xml.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: my game list should look like this.. |opponent name|  |last move|  |points|  |time since last move|  |whose turn?|

Answer (score 0):

You need not add data dynamically to the xml. You can just create some base layout in XML.

You can get that layout using findviewbyid and then keep adding the data using the java for that layout.

You can find many samples of creating /adding layouts in java.

Answer (score 0):

ok, then add a layout in your xml, and have a reference of this layout as a field in activity, 
Create views like:

for Layouts:

LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);

to set layout param on view or layout use:

ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

example to create views,

TextView txt= new TextView(this);
txt.setText(name);

To add view to layout use:
ll.addView(txt);

to add layout to parent layout, use:
parent.addView(ll);

Comment: this is my xml<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/GameListHolder"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gameList"
                    android:layout_width="70dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Answer (score 0):

use method like following,

```
holder=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.GameListHolder);
JSONObject jresponse=response.getJsonResponseFor(myRequest);

                String result=jresponse.toString();
                System.out.println(" jresponse is here  "+jresponse.toString());


                JSONArray jArray = jresponse.getJSONArray("games");
                int max=jArray.length();
                System.out.println("array length::"+max);

                for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
                   {

                JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
                JSONArray names = obj.names();

                for (int k = 0; k < names.length(); k++) 
                    {
                        String name = names.getString(k);
                        String value= obj.getString(name);

                         //Fetch values here      
                         createtableLayout(opponentName, lastMove,points, time, sinceLastMove, whose turn);  
                    }

                   }


    public void createtableLayout(String opponentName, String lastMove, String points, 
                   String time, String sinceLastMove, String whoseTurn)
    {
         LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new                                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         TextView txtOppName=new TextView(this);
         txtOppName.setText(txtOppName);
         ll.addView(txtOppName);

TextView txtOppName=new TextView(this);
         txtOppName.setText(txtOppName);
         ll.addView(txtOppName);
          ......

       holder.addView(ll);
}
    }
```